# confusing psql error: could not connect to server: FATAL: role "root" does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to build a RESTapi with spring, using docker image of postgre sql. I am running into this error when I try to run my script to build database and create tables.

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

I'm aware there is a lot of posts on SO that have asked similar questions. Why I'm still confused is that the instructions provided in the solution is always to use the -U flag to specify a user other than root. Yet, I am already doing that when I try to run this script, so im unsure what the problem is.

```
//copy the script to my docker container
$ docker cp expensetracker_db.sql postgresdb:/

//build container and enter bash to execute the script
docker container exec -it postgresdb bash

//succeeds. try to run the sql script
$ psql -U postgres ==file expensetracker_db.sql

//and...
psql:expensetracker_db.sql:1: ERROR:  database "expensetrackerdb" does not exist
DROP ROLE
CREATE ROLE
psql:expensetracker_db.sql:5: error: \connect: FATAL:  database "expensetrackerdb" does not exist
```

I am VERY new to docker, so excuse any mistakes I made in my language describing this situation. I suspect its possible there is something very obvious that i'm not noticing in my approach. but to me, it seems like the problem i'm getting should be taken care of by the -U argument i'm supplying when I run the script.

Heres the script. It seems syntax error free to me, but my SQL is a bit rusty..

```
drop database expensetrackerdb;
drop user expensetracker;
create user expensetracker with password 'password';
create database expensetrackerdb with template=template0 owner=expensetracker
\connect expensetrackerdb;
alter default privaleges grant all on tables to expensetracker;
alter default privaleges grant all on sequences to expensetracker;

create table et_users(
    user_id integer primary key not null,
    first_name varchar(28) not null,
    last_name varchar(28) not null,
    email varchar(30) not null,
    password text not null
);

create table et_categories(
    category_id integer primary key not null,
    user_id integer not null,
    title varchar(20) not null,
    description varchar(50) not null
);

alter table et_categories add constraint cat_users_fk
foreign key (user_id) references et_users(user_id);

create table et_transactions(
    transaction_id integer primary key not null,
    category_id integer not null,
    user_id integer not null,
    amount numeric(18,2) not null,
    note varchar(50) not null,
    transaction_data bigint not null
);

alter table et_transactions add constraint trans_cat_fk
foreign key (category_id) references et_categories(category_id);
alter table et_transactions add constraint trans_user_fk
foreign key (user_id) references et_users(user_id);

create sequence et_users_seq increment 1 start 1;
create sequence et_categories_seq increment 1 start 1;
create sequence et_transactions_seq increment 1 start 1000;
```

Comment: Well this `==file expensetracker_db.sql` should be `-f expensetracker_db.sql` or ` --file=expensetracker_db.sql

Comment: It looks like you're missing a semicolon at the end of line 4. If you add a semicolon there, does that help?

Comment: yes these both help. also mispelled privileges. Thank you